# How to add csv file in QGIS 2.0 using Delimited Text Layer Plugin?

Tags: qgis, csv, mac

I used to import csv files in previous versions of QGIS using the format below, but when I upgraded to QGIS 2.0 the delimited text layer plugin was changed and I can't import the file anymore. The plugin can't also detect the x,y or long lat field unlike in previous versions. Any ideas how to add the file? Thanks

[image: Format]

[image: Sample]

Heres what it looks in Text Editor:

[image]

Comment: It's weird that the different values from same file are appearing in the spreadsheet program that you have, and in Qgis. Can you show us how the data looks in a Text Editor? You should also check the 'First record has field names' option while importing it to Qgis.

Comment: I don't understand where the "Species" field_1 comes from, but it seems the linebreak in your data gets lost. Also, your decimal separator isn't a comma, but a colon apparently. Maybe this mixes things up?

Comment: Thanks @DevdattaTengshe for your prompt response. Please see above screenshot of the file in text editor.

Comment: Thanks too @SAnderka! I don't know why the field looks like that, but the delimiter is a comma. Please see screenshot above.

Comment: But your coordinates use a colon as decimal separator (you have '120.4833333', not '120,4833333'). What happens if you uncheck "Field optopons" > "Decimal separator is comma"?

Comment: Try using Custom delimers, and then use semicolon.

Comment: @SAnderka nothing happens when I unchecked it.

Comment: Thanks @AlexandreNeto! I used Custom delimiters > semicolon and field changed to "Species,Long,Lat SP1,120....,16.5...."

Comment: Thanks for all your help guys! I really appreciate it. I will try to work this out on my Window machine.

Comment: Hm. Unfortunately I only have good old QGIS 1.8 installed here at the office, and not 2.0 yet - otherwise I'd give your data a test run myself...

Comment: Do you have excel and open the text file in it...or copy and paste to it. use text to columes and import it from there.

Comment: Have you solved your problem? Your file is comma separated, and use colon as decimal separator. I would use the text editor to replace all "," to ";", and all "." to "," then I would use semi-colon separator, and it should work well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a problem with your text file (encoding ?)

The text file (not with TextEdit !)

[image]

The only thing I did is to fix X and Y fields

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: You're awesome!Thank you so much. I encoded the data using microsoft excel (which I used to do), but when I encoded it using LibreOffice I was able to import it.

Answer (score 2):

The line breaks are in Classic Mac (CR); they should be in Unix (LF).

I fixed this by opening my file in TextWrangler and changing the line encoding in the save as screen.

[image: Save as screen]