# Unable to merge CSV and CSVT with shapefile using QGIS due to "text" fields?

Tags: qgis, csv, attribute-joins, table

I know the question is all over this site, unfortunately I cannot find a solution. I have [this CSV file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7085068/codice%20comuni.csv) and [this CSVT file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7085068/codice%20comuni.csvt) that I want to merge with [this shapefile](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7085068/comuni%20provincia%20torino.zip). I've tried to format the .csv using all software mentioned in the forum including Excel, Numbers, Open Office, Libre Office, Text Edit and Sublime text.

The .csv file is imported almost correctly as you can see from the pictures, but the fields are wrong. Therefore the merge function does not work, because the csv fields are still seen as "text".

Can someone give me a hand on this?

[image]

Comment: both the fields look like they should be text anyway, what datatype do you want them to be?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Join non-spatial CSV to spatial data in QGIS](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6398/join-non-spatial-csv-to-spatial-data-in-qgis)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the answer to [QGIS 2.0 text delimited layer importing data as single row](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/76142/qgis-2-0-text-delimited-layer-importing-data-as-single-row):

> The Add delimited text layer plugin does not use the .csvt file. The
>   .csvt file is only interpreted by OGR - that means when you load the
>   .csv using Add vector layer.

You will find some hints on Mac-specific problems with delimited text too.

Apart from that, I see no common field in your data except the name field. PRO_COM contains different values than Zona in the csv table.

You can join on the name field, and get this picture:

[image]

30 Communes get coloured categorized by the joined field Zona, except for C015 and C020, which are spelled slightly different in the tables.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to see this post: [Joining non-spatial CSV file to spatial data (shapefile) using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6398/join-non-spatial-csv-to-spatial-data-in-qgis)

And here is a video demo on how to join CSV data to Shapefiles in QGIS: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=82aRDdJdhI0