# Qgis delimited text layer from an excel file converted to .csv

Tags: qgis, layers, csv, excel, mac

I'm trying to add a delimited text layer using coordinates. The file has been created in excel and then converted to a csv file in the saving. When I put it into Qgis it doesn't recognise the headings- it puts all the cells as headings and doesn't recognise all the data. none of the headings are just numbers. Attached is a screenshot of the data I'm trying to import. Any ideas as to where I could be going wrong?

[image]

Comment: When importing a delimited text layer, there is an option called **"First record has field names"**. Was this checked?

Comment: Since you work on a mac: Possible duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/137260/qgis-wont-read-table-columns-in-csv-import-on-mac-os and http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/76142/qgis-2-0-text-delimited-layer-importing-data-as-single-row/141315#141315

Comment: Yeah the First record has field names was checked. It puts all the headings on and then loads more as 'fields' and then says at the bottom that there is  'no data found in file'... I'm very confused. When I try and import other files the data is just immediately recognised which is why I thought it must be something wrong with the excel file I made.

Comment: perhaps one of your fields has a comma, and this is what's causing the problem. perhaps try saving it as tab separated or as pipe (`|`) separated.

Comment: I've realised it was because I needed to save it as a 'windows comma separated' values file, not just a .csv file. Thankyou for the links Andre!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asker "needed to save it as a 'windows comma separated' values file, not just a .csv file" which also solved the problem for me.