# How to add Excel-sheets with meter coordinates to QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinates, excel

I have an Excel-sheet where the coordinates are in meters. What is the most efficient way of inputting this file to QGIS? There are thousands of files to put so please recommend some straight-forward solution.

Comment: What do you mean with inputting? Do you want to generate a point layer? Coordinates in meters according to what? Please specify the nature of your data.

Comment: Sorry, by inputting I meant importing. I have Excel-sheets where the coordinates are in Adindan / UTM zone 37N -format. I need to be able to import those sheets to QGIS and project the points on a map.

Comment: Making plots of thousands of files is probably best done using a script, e.g. written in R.

Answer (score 1):

You save the sheet as a CSV file (Comma Separate Values format) and then import the layer as Delimited Text. In older versions of QGIS this feature was available as an installed plugin. Now it is available directly from the Layer menu.

see

[How to add csv file in QGIS 2.0 using Delimited Text Layer Plugin?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73961/how-to-add-csv-file-in-qgis-2-0-using-delimited-text-layer-plugin)

[QGIS 2.0 text delimited layer importing data as single row](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/76142/qgis-2-0-text-delimited-layer-importing-data-as-single-row)

Comment: I know the CSV importing, but it only accepts the coordinates in degrees or in DMS. I have the coordinates in Adindan / UTM zone 37N -format. This is the problem...

Comment: @Kimmo: That's not correct. The input data can be in any CRS.

Comment: Under `Settings -> Options`, CRS tab you can specify that QGIS should prompt you for the CRS of new layers, instead of using WGS84 as default.

Comment: Hmm. When I try to import the data, Q-GIS creates the "Delimited text file" in WGS-84 without asking to put the CRS. I cannot see the coordinate points of the file on a map.

Comment: Problem solved. There was a thousand separator in the Excel-file which prevented the correct file formation. Now it works like a dream. Thanks for pushing me to try more!

Answer (score 1):

You may also wish to try the "XY Tools" Plugin, that will let you read Excel files directly, without saving them to .csv first.

Comment: Thank you very much. That would be great. I will test it right away.